# Vue JS - Show 1 item in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, validation

I have an array of errorMessages which displays the validation errors to a particular field. For an email two validation errors apply; required and email validation.

I would like to have these display 1 at a time according to the, meaning that if the field is left empty, I want 'Email is required' to be displayed, but at the moment, if its left empty, both 'email is required' and 'email is incorrect' would be displayed.

Can someone suggest how I can let the error messages display one at a time?

```
<div v-show="apiError || errorMessages.length > 0">
    <p v-if="apiError && displayApiError" :class="{'text-error-right': customTextErrorClass}" class="text-error">{{apiError}}</p>
    <p v-else v-for="(error, index) of errorMessages" :key=index :class="{'text-error-right': customTextErrorClass}" class="text-error">{{error}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just use a v-if for each error separately.

Comment: `errorMessages[0]` will work in your case if the `Email is required` is always first.